# How to write a code to read input in separate lines from an input file and do the same thing this code does in C

Tags: c

I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char numbers[2001];
    char a[1000], b[1000];
    int int1, int2, i, n = 0;
    int sum, difference;

    fgets(numbers, sizeof(numbers), stdin);

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] != ' ')
        {
           a[i] = numbers[i];
        }
        else if (numbers[i] == ' ') {
            i += 1;
            b[n] = numbers[i];
            for (n = 1; n < 1000; n++)
                b[n] = numbers[n+i];
        }


    }

    int1=atoi(a);
    int2=atoi(b);

    sum = int1 + int2;
    difference = int1 - int2;
    printf("%d\n%d", sum, difference);

    return 0;
 }
```

But there are several lines of 2 numbers in input file. And I want the program to find the sum and difference for each line and print them.

Here is an example of an input:

```
12 45
36 111
9 5
153 6
```

output:

```
57
33
147
-75
14
4
159
147
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sscanf` for getting the number from the string, it's more simple:

```
    FILE * fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) {
       return -1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(numbers, sizeof(numbers), fp)) {
        sscanf(numbers, "%d %d", &a[i], &b[i]);
        printf("sum = %d\n", a[i]+b[i]);
        printf("diff = %d\n", abs(a[i] - b[i]));
        i++;
    }
```

You should change the type of `a` and `b` from `char` to `int` for the big number.

```
int a[1000], b[100];
```

Because the numbers in my code is the line of the input file, and it content of 2 number, so you can decrease its size:

```
char numbers[256]; // for example.
```

The complete for test:

```
int main(void) {
    char numbers[256];
    int a[1000], b[1000];
    FILE * fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) {
       return -1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(numbers, sizeof(numbers), fp) && i < 1000) {
        sscanf(numbers, "%d %d", &a[i], &b[i]);
        i++;
    }

    for(int j = 0, j < i; j++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", a[j], b[j]);
        printf("sum = %d\n", a[j]+b[j]);
        printf("diff = %d\n", abs(a[j] - b[j]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The input and output:

```
#cat input.txt
12 45
36 111
9 5
153 6

./test
12 45
sum = 57
diff = 33
36 111
sum = 147
diff = 75
9 5
sum = 14
diff = 4
153 6
sum = 159
diff = 147
```

Comment: `a` and `b` no longer need to be arrays.  If you make them both `int`, you can also get rid of `i` and eliminate the problem that occurs when the input file has more than 1000 lines.  Probably wouldn't hurt to check the return value from `sscanf` to make sure it parsed two integers.

Comment: we can just `a` and `b` as the `int` type. Maybe, the OP need to store the value for do something else, so i remain the array `a` and `b`.

Comment: I agree with you for limit the lines and check the return from the `sscanf`. I just want to propose an example. BTW, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I want the output after all inputs not right after the first input. I mean, input should be a few lines and the output for each lines should be given only after. I don't understand how to do that

Comment: All values are stored in two arrays a and b. So, if you print the outputs after the inputs, let's print it after while loop

Comment: Thanks very much !! :)